# Arduino C++: Does the F() macro make any sense inside a function?

Tags: c++, function, memory-management, arduino, arduino-esp8266

The F() macro is useful to store global vars in program memory (flash storage) instead of dynamic work memory so there is more free memory left.

However, I came across this messy example included at the ESP8266 library. It works fine however I have some doubts about the usage of the F() macro inside the functions. Is it useful to use it inside functions?

---

Example code:

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiClient.h>
#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>
#include <DNSServer.h>
#include <ESP8266mDNS.h>
#include <EEPROM.h>

/*
   This example serves a "hello world" on a WLAN and a SoftAP at the same time.
   The SoftAP allow you to configure WLAN parameters at run time. They are not setup in the sketch but saved on EEPROM.
   Connect your computer or cell phone to wifi network ESP_ap with password 12345678. A popup may appear and it allow you to go to WLAN config. If it does not then navigate to http://192.168.4.1/wifi and config it there.
   Then wait for the module to connect to your wifi and take note of the WLAN IP it got. Then you can disconnect from ESP_ap and return to your regular WLAN.
   Now the ESP8266 is in your network. You can reach it through http://192.168.x.x/ (the IP you took note of) or maybe at http://esp8266.local too.
   This is a captive portal because through the softAP it will redirect any http request to http://192.168.4.1/
*/

/* Set these to your desired softAP credentials. They are not configurable at runtime */
#ifndef APSSID
#define APSSID "TheGeekMan"
#define APPSK  "12345678"
#endif

const char *softAP_ssid = APSSID;
const char *softAP_password = APPSK;

/* hostname for mDNS. Should work at least on windows. Try http://esp8266.local */
const char *myHostname = "thegeekman";

/* Don't set this wifi credentials. They are configurated at runtime and stored on EEPROM */
char ssid[32] = "";
char password[32] = "";

// DNS server
const byte DNS_PORT = 53;
DNSServer dnsServer;

// Web server
ESP8266WebServer server(80);

/* Soft AP network parameters */
//IPAddress apIP(192, 168, 4, 1);
IPAddress apIP(8, 8, 8, 8);
IPAddress netMsk(255, 255, 255, 0);


/** Should I connect to WLAN asap? */
boolean connect;

/** Last time I tried to connect to WLAN */
unsigned long lastConnectTry = 0;

/** Current WLAN status */
unsigned int status = WL_IDLE_STATUS;

/** Is this an IP? */
boolean isIp(String str) {
  for (size_t i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
    int c = str.charAt(i);
    if (c != '.' && (c < '0' || c > '9')) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}

/** IP to String? */
String toStringIp(IPAddress ip) {
  String res = "";
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    res += String((ip >> (8 * i)) & 0xFF) + ".";
  }
  res += String(((ip >> 8 * 3)) & 0xFF);
  return res;
}

/** Load WLAN credentials from EEPROM */
void loadCredentials() {
  EEPROM.begin(512);
  EEPROM.get(0, ssid);
  EEPROM.get(0 + sizeof(ssid), password);
  char ok[2 + 1];
  EEPROM.get(0 + sizeof(ssid) + sizeof(password), ok);
  EEPROM.end();
  if (String(ok) != String("OK")) {
    ssid[0] = 0;
    password[0] = 0;
  }
  Serial.println("Recovered credentials:");
  Serial.println(ssid);
  Serial.println(strlen(password) > 0 ? "********" : "<no password>");
}

/** Store WLAN credentials to EEPROM */
void saveCredentials() {
  EEPROM.begin(512);
  EEPROM.put(0, ssid);
  EEPROM.put(0 + sizeof(ssid), password);
  char ok[2 + 1] = "OK";
  EEPROM.put(0 + sizeof(ssid) + sizeof(password), ok);
  EEPROM.commit();
  EEPROM.end();
}

/** Handle root or redirect to captive portal */
void handleRoot() {
  if (captivePortal()) { // If caprive portal redirect instead of displaying the page.
    return;
  }
  server.sendHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
  server.sendHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
  server.sendHeader("Expires", "-1");

  String Page;
  Page += F(
            "<html><head></head><body>"
            "<h1>HELLO WORLD!!</h1>");
  if (server.client().localIP() == apIP) {
    Page += String(F("<p>You are connected through the soft AP: ")) + softAP_ssid + F("</p>");
  } else {
    Page += String(F("<p>You are connected through the wifi network: ")) + ssid + F("</p>");
  }
  Page += F(
            "<p>You may want to <a href='/wifi'>config the wifi connection</a>.</p>"
            "</body></html>");

  server.send(200, "text/html", Page);
}

/** Redirect to captive portal if we got a request for another domain. Return true in that case so the page handler do not try to handle the request again. */
boolean captivePortal() {
  if (!isIp(server.hostHeader()) && server.hostHeader() != (String(myHostname) + ".local")) {
    Serial.println("Request redirected to captive portal");
    server.sendHeader("Location", String("http://") + toStringIp(server.client().localIP()), true);
    server.send(302, "text/plain", "");   // Empty content inhibits Content-length header so we have to close the socket ourselves.
    server.client().stop(); // Stop is needed because we sent no content length
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}

/** Wifi config page handler */
void handleWifi() {
  server.sendHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
  server.sendHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
  server.sendHeader("Expires", "-1");

  String Page;
  Page += F(
            "<html><head></head><body>"
            "<h1>Wifi config</h1>");
  if (server.client().localIP() == apIP) {
    Page += String(F("<p>You are connected through the soft AP: ")) + softAP_ssid + F("</p>");
  } else {
    Page += String(F("<p>You are connected through the wifi network: ")) + ssid + F("</p>");
  }
  Page +=
    String(F(
             "\r\n<br />"
             "<table><tr><th align='left'>SoftAP config</th></tr>"
             "<tr><td>SSID ")) +
    String(softAP_ssid) +
    F("</td></tr>"
      "<tr><td>IP ") +
    toStringIp(WiFi.softAPIP()) +
    F("</td></tr>"
      "</table>"
      "\r\n<br />"
      "<table><tr><th align='left'>WLAN config</th></tr>"
      "<tr><td>SSID ") +
    String(ssid) +
    F("</td></tr>"
      "<tr><td>IP ") +
    toStringIp(WiFi.localIP()) +
    F("</td></tr>"
      "</table>"
      "\r\n<br />"
      "<table><tr><th align='left'>WLAN list (refresh if any missing)</th></tr>");
  Serial.println("scan start");
  int n = WiFi.scanNetworks();
  Serial.println("scan done");
  if (n > 0) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      Page += String(F("\r\n<tr><td>SSID ")) + WiFi.SSID(i) + ((WiFi.encryptionType(i) == ENC_TYPE_NONE) ? F(" ") : F(" *")) + F(" (") + WiFi.RSSI(i) + F(")</td></tr>");
    }
  } else {
    Page += F("<tr><td>No WLAN found</td></tr>");
  }
  Page += F(
            "</table>"
            "\r\n<br /><form method='POST' action='wifisave'><h4>Connect to network:</h4>"
            "<input type='text' placeholder='network' name='n'/>"
            "<br /><input type='password' placeholder='password' name='p'/>"
            "<br /><input type='submit' value='Connect/Disconnect'/></form>"
            "<p>You may want to <a href='/'>return to the home page</a>.</p>"
            "</body></html>");
  server.send(200, "text/html", Page);
  server.client().stop(); // Stop is needed because we sent no content length
}

/** Handle the WLAN save form and redirect to WLAN config page again */
void handleWifiSave() {
  Serial.println("wifi save");
  server.arg("n").toCharArray(ssid, sizeof(ssid) - 1);
  server.arg("p").toCharArray(password, sizeof(password) - 1);
  server.sendHeader("Location", "wifi", true);
  server.sendHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
  server.sendHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
  server.sendHeader("Expires", "-1");
  server.send(302, "text/plain", "");    // Empty content inhibits Content-length header so we have to close the socket ourselves.
  server.client().stop(); // Stop is needed because we sent no content length
  saveCredentials();
  connect = strlen(ssid) > 0; // Request WLAN connect with new credentials if there is a SSID
}

void handleNotFound() {
  if (captivePortal()) { // If caprive portal redirect instead of displaying the error page.
    return;
  }
  String message = F("File Not Found\n\n");
  message += F("URI: ");
  message += server.uri();
  message += F("\nMethod: ");
  message += (server.method() == HTTP_GET) ? "GET" : "POST";
  message += F("\nArguments: ");
  message += server.args();
  message += F("\n");

  for (uint8_t i = 0; i < server.args(); i++) {
    message += String(F(" ")) + server.argName(i) + F(": ") + server.arg(i) + F("\n");
  }
  server.sendHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
  server.sendHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
  server.sendHeader("Expires", "-1");
  server.send(404, "text/plain", message);
}

void setup() {
  delay(1000);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println("Configuring access point...");
  /* You can remove the password parameter if you want the AP to be open. */
  WiFi.softAPConfig(apIP, apIP, netMsk);
  WiFi.softAP(softAP_ssid, softAP_password);
  delay(500); // Without delay I've seen the IP address blank
  Serial.print("AP IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.softAPIP());

  /* Setup the DNS server redirecting all the domains to the apIP */
  dnsServer.setErrorReplyCode(DNSReplyCode::NoError);
  dnsServer.start(DNS_PORT, "*", apIP);

  /* Setup web pages: root, wifi config pages, SO captive portal detectors and not found. */
  server.on("/", handleRoot);
  server.on("/wifi", handleWifi);
  server.on("/wifisave", handleWifiSave);
  server.on("/generate_204", handleRoot);  //Android captive portal. Maybe not needed. Might be handled by notFound handler.
  server.on("/fwlink", handleRoot);  //Microsoft captive portal. Maybe not needed. Might be handled by notFound handler.
  server.onNotFound(handleNotFound);
  server.begin(); // Web server start
  Serial.println("HTTP server started");
  loadCredentials(); // Load WLAN credentials from network
  connect = strlen(ssid) > 0; // Request WLAN connect if there is a SSID
}

void connectWifi() {
  Serial.println("Connecting as wifi client...");
  WiFi.disconnect();
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  int connRes = WiFi.waitForConnectResult();
  Serial.print("connRes: ");
  Serial.println(connRes);
}

void loop() {
  if (connect) {
    Serial.println("Connect requested");
    connect = false;
    connectWifi();
    lastConnectTry = millis();
  }
  {
    unsigned int s = WiFi.status();
    if (s == 0 && millis() > (lastConnectTry + 60000)) {
      /* If WLAN disconnected and idle try to connect */
      /* Don't set retry time too low as retry interfere the softAP operation */
      connect = true;
    }
    if (status != s) { // WLAN status change
      Serial.print("Status: ");
      Serial.println(s);
      status = s;
      if (s == WL_CONNECTED) {
        /* Just connected to WLAN */
        Serial.println("");
        Serial.print("Connected to ");
        Serial.println(ssid);
        Serial.print("IP address: ");
        Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());

        // Setup MDNS responder
        if (!MDNS.begin(myHostname)) {
          Serial.println("Error setting up MDNS responder!");
        } else {
          Serial.println("mDNS responder started");
          // Add service to MDNS-SD
          MDNS.addService("http", "tcp", 80);
        }
      } else if (s == WL_NO_SSID_AVAIL) {
        WiFi.disconnect();
      }
    }
    if (s == WL_CONNECTED) {
      MDNS.update();
    }
  }
  // Do work:
  //DNS
  dnsServer.processNextRequest();
  //HTTP
  server.handleClient();
}
```

---

A function is stored in program space (program memory) so the strings inside this function are also compiled into program space. So why do they use the F() macro to force to store strings in program space while it is normally already loaded from program space? I think it is unnecessary overhead or are there any benefits to do it this way?

---

For example, in the source code you can found many of these assignments inside functions:

```
void handleWifi()
{
  String Page;
  Page+= F("<html><head></head><body>"
           "<h1>Wifi config</h1>");
  .........
  .........
}
```

---

What wil happen here is that the string is loaded from program space into dynamic memory (as variable 'Page'). So what is the real deal here? However I think the C++ compiler will do a much better job (optimization) when it was just a simple assignment.

Am I right or am I wrong?

Comment: `A function is stored in program space (program memory) so the strings inside this function are also compiled into program space` - yes, but the string is copied _also_ in volatile memory (RAM). So it is duplicated.

Comment: @Kamil Cuk You seems to be right, that is why I decide to do a test, see also my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, I was **wrong**, sorry, F() makes also sense inside functions. To prove it, i did some tests.

Did some tests with this simple sketch (uncomment the one you want to test):

```
// Printing 33 chars
// 1.
//void printStr() { Serial.println( "0123456789ABCDEFGHo!@#$%^&*()_+<>?" ); }
//void printStr() { Serial.println( F("0123456789ABCDEFGHo!@#$%^&*()_+<>?" )); }
// 2.
void printStr() { String s = "0123456789ABCDEFGHo!@#$%^&*()_+<>?"; Serial.println( s ); }
//void printStr() { String s; s+=F("0123456789ABCDEFGHo!@#$%^&*()_+<>?"); Serial.println( s ); }

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
 printStr();
 delay(1000);
}
```

Results:

**Without** use of **F()** 26816 bytes

```
The sketch uses 263136 bytes (25%) of program storage space. Maximum is 1044464 bytes.
Global variables use 26816 bytes (32%) of the dynamic memory. 
Remain 55104 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 81920 bytes.
```

**With** use of **F()** 26788 bytes

```
The sketch uses 263212 bytes (25%) of program storage space. Maximum is 1044464 bytes.
Global variables use 26788 bytes (32%) of the dynamic memory. 
Remain 55132 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 81920 bytes.
```

-28 bytes difference with F(). But okay, now we know for sure! ;-)

---

### Update 11 jan 2019

**Background info why it works this way:**

The RAM is split up into different chunks for different purposes. There’s a chunk where all the global and static variables are stored (aka BSS and data areas). There’s the stack where local variables created within function are stored, and finally there’s the heap, which is where dynamic variables are stored.

If you want to know more about how these chunks of memory relate to each other you can read more on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_segment).

---

*Info copied from this [article](https://hackingmajenkoblog.wordpress.com/2016/02/04/the-evils-of-arduino-strings/).*

Answer (score 0):

It's, probably, because of reason that described here:
http://playground.arduino.cc/Learning/Memory

> there is a lot more Flash (program) memory than SRAM available
>   When you create variables with the Arduino language such as:
>
> `char message[] = "I support the Cape Wind project.";`
>
> You are copying 33 bytes (1 char = 1 byte, plus terminating null) from
>   program memory into SRAM before using it. 33 bytes isn't a lot of
>   memory in a pool of 1024 bytes, but if the sketch requires some large
>   unchanging data structures - such as a large amount of text to send to
>   a display, or a large lookup table, for example - using flash memory
>   (program memory) directly for storage may be the only option. To do
>   this, use the PROGMEM keyword.

Comment: Empty page when visiting link??? That's true however this is about GLOBAL variables, they don't mention anything about vars inside functions.

Comment: @Codebeat, It was something with site) Now it's active. And no, this is not about global variables. This is about string literals (strings in double quotes). They all are global, because they should be inlined inside of executable file. Normally, when compiler compiles executable file(.hex file) they all copied to section that then loaded to SRAM (there all constants stored). But, when you use F macro, compiler left all them inside code, and creates asm-code(i mean opcodes) that reads that literals as strings from SRAM and not used them as code. Also reading faster than from SRAM.

Comment: You seems to be right, that is why I decide to do a test, see also my answer.